# How do I read the contents of wallet.dat in C#

Tags: wallet, development

I'd like to be able to add, remove, export etc. keypairs from my wallet.dat file. Looking over the source code of [pywallet](https://github.com/joric/pywallet) it doesn't look like such a tough task, but of course it's not as simple as `from bsddb.db import *` in C# and Google is failing me. Does anyone have some sample code or resources for how to handle wallet.dat in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wallet.dat is a Berkeley DB file.  You could check out [Berkeley DB for .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdb-dotnet/) to see if it is able to read the file.

Comment: For some reason I can't build this. I get a ton of these type of error: `Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'out BerkeleyDb.DB_SEQUENCE_STAT*' is less accessible than delegate 'BerkeleyDb.DB_SEQUENCE.StatFcn' C:\Users\enmaku\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\libdb-dotnet\src\DB_SEQUENCE.cs 146 30 libdb_dotNET45`

Comment: VS2010 Win7 x64 if it matters.

Comment: There are precompiled binaries in the Files section of the sourceforge project you could try.

Comment: The precompiled binaries worked well enough. If I figure it out 100% I'll start a github repo and link to it here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Erv mentioned, the [next version of the wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4809/1878) may be using LevelDB for the block chain and some custom format for the private key store.

Here is more information on the [LevelDB access from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292648/is-there-a-good-port-of-leveldb-for-c) but I hope someone updates this post with a link to the best LevelDB for C# for our purposes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BitcoinSharp](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinsharp/), a port of [bitcoinj](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/).

Comment: I hadn't considered that BitcoinSharp, being a direct port of Bitcoin to C# would, by necessity, contain the necessary code to handle wallet.dat (duh). I'd much rather have a small snippet of sample code than dig through the whole BitcoinSharp project, but given that Erv's link goes to unbuildable code this may be my only choice...

Comment: And now I get `The input stream is not a valid binary format` opening a perfectly valid wallet.dat with `Wallet.LoadFromFile` - has anyone actually USED this before?

Comment: Glancing over the code it looks like BitcoinSharp just serializes and deserializes its wallet object with a BinaryFormatter, it doesn't appear to use the Berkeley DB format that the regular Bitcoin client does, so this is unfortunately a dead end :(

Comment: BitcoinSharp and bitcoinj use a different wallet format than using by bitcoin-core.